# Jquery .parent().attr() returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm trying to get the parent's attribute value and display that as text inside the child's `div`. It's returning as undefined.

My HTML:

```
<div class="info" data-info="whatever I want displayed" ></div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(function(){ 
  var $info = $(this).parent().attr("data-info");
  $('.info').prepend($('<div class="new-info" >' + $info + '</div>'));
});`
```

My desired result:

```
<div class="info" data-info="whatever I want displayed" >
  <div class="new-info" >whatever I want displayed</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the context of `this`? If that's all the javascript you have, `this` refers to the window object, and not a dom element. How can `.info` be a parent when it's empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no parent. And `$(this)` on the first line is not refer to info element. You need to select `.info` element first and followed by prepend like so :

```
$(function(){ 
  // and if you already use html5 data attribute
  // you can just select it value by using .data()
  var 
     $info = $('.info'),
     dataInfo = $info.data("info");

     $info.prepend('<div class="new-info" >' + dataInfo + '</div>');
});
```

Comment: If you're going to do that, it makes sense to cache `$('.info')`.

Comment: Thank you, It is working now. But what if I have several of these elements with different `data-info` values? It seems to only return the value of the first element to all of them.

Comment: You can traverse by using `.closest()` to find matched parent and at the end find the child element based on previous parent we found. It depends on your HTML structured.

Comment: As far as the HTML structure goes, the `.info`s would most likely be siblings. There would never be an `.info` inside of another `.info`.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!